# How to pass multiple fields in Queryparser in Lucene?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

Can i pass multiple index fields in a Querparser in Lucene?
I have done something like this

```
  QueryParser queryParser =  MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse(new[] { query }, new[] { "Name", "Description", "ExternalIdentifier", "OriginalFileName", "Text" }, new StandardAnalyzer());
  queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
```

But it shows some error? i am little bit confused can anybody give me a help?

Comment: Cant pass multiple fields like this? then how can we pass multiple index fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/MultiFieldQueryParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer%29) for the specific overload of `MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse` that you are using states the following:

> `IllegalArgumentException` - 
>   if the length of the queries, fields,
>   and flags array differ.

I suspect you are getting this exception as you have one query and 5 fields.  If this is the method that you want to use, you must provide an array of queries with a length of five.

You *may* want to use a [different parse overload](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/MultiFieldQueryParser.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause.Occur%5B%5D,%20org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer%29), which will take a single query but multiple fields and flags.

Comment: So for checking  in multiple index field do i have to use multiple overloads ? or is there any way of checking for a query in multiple fields in a single statement?

Comment: You can use the single overload.  However, I not 100% sure if this is what you want.  Here is an example:

MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse(new[] { query }, new[] { "Name", "Description"}, new[] { BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD }, new StandardAnalyzer());

Comment: Have you tried this answer [Lucene QueryParser two fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005084/lucene-queryparser-two-fields)?  Looks like your question may be a dupe.