# Search across fields in Lucene

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I'm a complete noobie with Lucene and so far a huge, huge fan.

I'm now looking for some resources on how to store data and search through c# and dotnet.  Any LINQ samples would be a big bonus to me.

In particular if I have a document that has two fields defined as say title and description, how can i search in both?

in the sample below i'd like to search both title and description fields.

eg:

```
        doc = new Document();
        text = "Oven leek pie";
        doc.Add(new Field("title", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
        doc.Add(new Field("instructions", "Bake for 40 minutes", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
        iwriter.AddDocument(doc);
```

and then;

```
        // Parse a simple query that searches for "text":
        Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("title", analyzer);

        Query query = parser.Parse("baked bacon and leek pizza");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
string[] fields = new string[2];
fields[0] = "title";
fields[1] = "instructions";

Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.MultiFieldQueryParser multiFieldParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer);
Query multiFieldQuery = multiFieldParser.Parse("20");
Hits multiHits = isearcher.Search(multiFieldQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to search across fields in Lucene. Sam Doshi describes several in this answer to another StackOverflow question:
[How to incorporate multiple fields in QueryParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468405/lucene-net-how-to-incorporate-multiple-fields-in-queryparser/2036898#2036898)