# How can I get NHibernate.Search FT query to use a "free text" query style?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, full-text-search, nhibernate-search

I'm trying to implement a text search option using the Lucene-based full-text search engine on my NHibernate-based MVC project (NHibernate.Search).  All the documentation I've seen on how to do this suggests I need to look at specific columns for values, something like:

```
            var query = "Title:Ford";
            using (var search = NHibernate.Search.Search.CreateFullTextSession(s))
            {                   
                using (var transaction = s.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var carSearchResults = search.CreateFullTextQuery(query)
                        .SetMaxResults(5)
                        .List();  
                    foreach(var car in carSearchResults)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(car.Title);
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
```

I would rather look at all full-text indexed columns for the search string, like you can do in SQL with a wildcard on the `FREETEXT` function... so I could do something like:

```
            var query = "Ford";
            using (var search = NHibernate.Search.Search.CreateFullTextSession(s))
            {                   
                using (var transaction = s.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var carSearchResults = search.CreateFullTextQuery(query)
                        .SetMaxResults(5)
                        .List();  
                    foreach(var car in carSearchResults)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(car.Title);
                    }
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
```

... and this would examine all full-text indexed properties for "Ford", and return all hits.  Is there a comparable function/ method/ syntax for this using the NHibernate-based search engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [How to incorporate multiple fields in QueryParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468405/how-to-incorporate-multiple-fields-in-queryparser)

Short answer, change:

```
var query = "Title:Ford";
```

to:

```
var query = "Title:Ford OR Name:Ford OR Field1:Ford OR Field2:Ford"; // etc for all fields
```

Comment: I used the multi field query thing you referenced; it was exactly what I was looking for and it worked like a champ.  Thanks!