# Lucene 4.0 getFieldInfos

Tags: java, lucene

I am pretty much trying to do this on lucene4.0 (java): [How to incorporate multiple fields in QueryParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468405/how-to-incorporate-multiple-fields-in-queryparser/2036898#2036898)

Though I'd like to search on all fields (all are not present on all documents) and I don't know their names. So here I found:

`QueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, ir.GetFieldNames(IndexReader.FieldOption.ALL).toArray(), analyzer)`

Though `getfieldNames()` has been replace in 4.0 by "[LUCENE-3679 Replace IndexReader.getFieldNames with IndexReader.getFieldInfos](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3679)".

However, the problem is that `getFieldNames` or any getField* is defined in [IndexReader](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/index.html).

I have been looking online for ages for a solution. What am I missing and how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FieldInfos are only available on [AtomicReader](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/AtomicReader.html#getFieldInfos%28%29). You can get a FieldInfos view on a composite reader by calling [MultiFields.getMergedFieldInfos](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/MultiFields.html#getMergedFieldInfos%28org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader%29).

Comment: Ho this looks perfect! I check and accept your answer. Thx a lot

Comment: Am I alone to find this a bit strange? Do you know if there is an underlying reason for this?

Comment: What do you find strange? If you are surprised that IndexReader doesn't expose composite FieldInfos. The reason is that Lucene tries to encourage people to compute things on a per-segment basis instead of using composite views which are slower. If you want to use a (slow) composite view anyway, you can call SlowCompositeReaderWrapper.wrap(IndexReader) to get an atomic view of a composite reader.

Comment: @charly Have a look at [this blog](http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/02/is-your-indexreader-atomic-major.html) if you want to know more. That will give you some more information about that choice.