# Lucene .Net multiple filters

Tags: .net, vb.net, lucene.net

I am using the Lucene dll (Version.LUCENE_30) for .Net 3.5.

I would like to add a bunch of fields to the document during indexing time and filter by those fields during retrieval time.

The code I use for indexing is as follows:

```
'These are analyzed fields
doc.Add(New Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("FileText", FileText, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.ANALYZED))
doc.Add(New Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("FileName", FileName, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Index.ANALYZED))

'These are non-analyzed fields. Would like to use these for filtering.
doc.Add(New Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("FieldA", FieldA, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED))
doc.Add(New Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("FieldB", FieldB, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED))
doc.Add(New Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("FieldC", FieldC, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Index.NOT_ANALYZED))
```

Could someone please suggest code for the retrieval side using the above filters? Say, the user is searching for the string 'Jack Reacher' by filtering on FieldA='Lee Child' and FieldB='Random' filters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to incorporate multiple fields in QueryParser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468405/how-to-incorporate-multiple-fields-in-queryparser)

Comment: Thanks David, this is useful.